# Does it make sense that a hash is separated by hyphens

Tags: hash

I'm trying to solve a challenge that is no longer active. I failed it when it was active, and I still can't resolve it. The challenge showed me a hash, and I have no idea what kind it is, and how does it make sense that parts of it are separated by hyphens?

I thought about `md5` , is it possible?

```
14d6532f-aefb-49c7-b418-89ddff7002d9
```

Comment: Have you ever considered the possible encodings? Normally, the hash functions work on bits, and usually, they have returned the result in bytes. Then, to view it, we encode it like hex, base64, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a [UUID format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Format). Note that this is a *representation* of a 128 bit string. Just like "9" is a representation of "1001".

The actual output of the hash is a random looking 128-bit string.

If it is a UUID, it can be different hash functions depending on what version it is.